# Is there a way to "reach into" a union nested inside an intersection?

Tags: typescript

Imagine that I have a type which is a union nested inside an intersection:

```
type UnionInsideIntersectionType = ({ foo: "foo" } | { foo: "bar" }) & {
  baz: "baz";
};
```

Is there a way to later extend the union portion of the type without rewriting it? In other words, can I somehow make the following from a transformation of `UnionInsideIntersectionType`?

```
type ExtendedUnionInsideIntersectionType = (
  | { foo: "foo" }
  | { foo: "bar" }
  | { foo: "qux" }
) & { baz: "baz" };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwJJwM4ICYXcCAJwwgGNhk4AVcaAXigAoBvKAMySQC4oAiDpLygBfKAB8orAT14AjAIaEhwgJRQAZJIBQUKAoBeMg7wDcW4WYD0lqAgxRgACyLR5UAO7yQDpFAC28gDW0ACiAB4EcLjY8JToWLj4RCTklDSQ7IRIflBa1rCIKPE4eHAExGQUKOnQ7ghOSACuwFCEEO6E9QhwAOa2wAD8WqAZ4ZHRsUWYJUkVqdW0UAyMOuKS7JwyAsqrElKbfApKIrvr0nwAjo1hO2qarAZG8vrKJkA)

Conversely, is there a way to do this subtractively, i.e. to remove `foo: "qux"` from `ExtendedUnionInsideIntersectionType` to produce `UnionInsideIntersectionType`? I'm aware of [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers), but if it can be applied to properties, I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) but I'll indulge it.

---

> Is there a way to later extend the union portion of the type without rewriting it?

From a pure logic, and type system, point of view this:

```
(A | B) & C
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
(A & C) | (B & C)
```

And typescript knows that. Which means figuring out what part is a union and which part is an intersection gets a bit muddy after the type is declared. And all you have to work with is the result. Artifacts of how the type was assembled can be seen in the tooltips the compiler provides sometimes, but functionally the two cases above are perfectly equivalent. There is no sense of order of operations after the type has been declared. It just is what it is.

Another example:

```
type A = ({ a: 1 } | { a: 2 }) & { b: 3 }
type B = { a: 1, b: 3 } | { a: 2, b: 3 }

type Test1 = A extends B ? true : false // true
type Test2 = B extends A ? true : false // true
```

All of which means that I believe the answer to your first question is "no".

---

> Conversely, is there a way to do this subtractively, i.e. to remove foo: "qux" from ExtendedUnionInsideIntersectionType to produce UnionInsideIntersectionType?

`Exclude` works great here:

```
type WithoutQux = Exclude<ExtendedUnionInsideIntersectionType, { foo: 'qux' }>
```

---

As an alternative, it seems like the `UnionInsideIntersectionType` type should be generic, which lets you inject whatever else you want in there.

```
type UnionInsideIntersectionType<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, never>
> = ({ foo: "foo" } | { foo: "bar" } | T) & { baz: "baz"; };

type ExtendedUnionInsideIntersectionType =
  UnionInsideIntersectionType<{ foo: 'qux' }>
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwJJwM4ICYXcCAJwwgGNhk4AVcCAHgCgooqoIAPAubDKAJTJJC2OhmCEEcAOYAaKAFc4AazhIA7nAB8UALz9Bw0eMmyocCADcimhtr0AKAN5QAZkiQAuKACI3Sb1AAvlAAPlDOfl7eAEYAhoQBwWFUAJRQAGThUHEAXlG53gDcQYUMDKCQUACinBDcENjwlOhYuPhEJOSUNJV6TSgtOHhwBMRkFCg99BHuXgDkAI7y7HNBNgD068xQAHoA-GUV0ADqCMAAFkjywACKy7rV7KQANvK4dDVcuI2IA5hD7TGXUmtDkM08UEWy1WgRs5VoUAAgg8nFBYl4AIxBUJZdFQABMQTSmWc0S8AGYgvDKgAhB7OPEYuRkqCUpK4rz45kUqnU6BUCBiLF6ZEcL68Ol7KDieTQLwuWLPEhQTbSwiyvksQXAQl6Oliuo8JFQKUyuWuRXK1VmoA)

Comment: I wasn't aware of [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) before seeing this. For anyone else in the dark about this, `= Record<string, never>` in the last example makes the type parameter optional.

Comment: Yep. And `Record<string, never>` looks weird but it basically means an empty object since the only valid value type is `never`. This lets you leave off the generic entirely if you don't want to inject anything.